# Как оперировать flex внутри одного блока, который тоже задан как display flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, выравнивание

Пытаюсь сделать домашнее задание по макету и не могу сделать `main-menu` по центру, а `architec-logo` в виде `<a><a/>` слева, [как показано тут](https://www.figma.com/file/5crsQK67YzIvQCKEGubOMT/Design-Architecture?node-id=3100%3A2).

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: #313131;
  display: flex;
}

.architect-logo {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main-menu-item {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.header-main {
  height: 337px;
  width: 1263px;
  background-image: url(/images/header-bg.jpeg);
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="architec-logo">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Arcitec</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="main-manu">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li class="main-menu-item">Home</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Architecture design</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Strange buildings</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Magszine</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Blog</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">News</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Что бы сделать такое на [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) потребуется задействовать дополнительный элемент-болванку, но он понадобиться ***только если есть необходимость выровнять само меню строго по центру с учетом логотипа***, более подробно я уже рассматривал этот момент здесь:

[Flex-box как игнорироваться родительский justify-content?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1161763/397819)

Рабочий пример на основе Вашего кода:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #313131;
}

.architec-logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu > ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.main-menu-item {
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.header-main {
  height: 337px;
  width: 1263px;
  background-image: url(/images/header-bg.jpeg);
}

.hidden-logo {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="architec-logo">
    <a class="logo">Arcitec</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Home</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Architecture design</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Strange buildings</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Magszine</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">Blog</li>
      <li class="main-menu-item">News</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="hidden-logo">
    <a class="logo">Arcitec</a>
  </div>
</header>
```